# How do use radio button in show dialog on Flutter for navigation?

Tags: navigation, radio-button, flutter, showdialog

I have a page and I have a button. When user tabs the button I need a simple dialog box that has 3 radio button. When user tabs the any button I need to set some text and based on text I need to navigate user to selected page.

Example: Account page has currency conversion description and user current amount shows in USD. When user tabs the button "Convert my amount to =>" it must open a dialog that has 3 radio button as, "STG", "EUR", "TRY". If user tabs the "STG" radio button I need to send the user to STG conversion page. Each conversion page has a different properties that user can interact.

How do use radio button in show dialog on Flutter for navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this if I understand you correctly. Didn't use the currency example but the idea is the same.

```
       PopupMenuButton(
          child: Text('Some Button'),
        itemBuilder: (_) => [
          PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Item1'), value: 'item1',),
          PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Item2'), value: 'item2'),
        ],
        onSelected: (value) => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(value),
      )
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job perfectly